# removing everything after first 'backslash' in a string

Tags: r, vector, gsub, stringr

I have a vector like below

```
vec <- c("abc\edw\www", "nmn\ggg", "rer\qqq\fdf"......)
```

I want to remove everything after as soon as first slash is encountered, like below

```
newvec <- c("abc","nmn","rer")
```

Thank you.

My original vector is as below (only the head)

```
[1] "peoria ave\nste \npeoria"                      [2]   "wood dr\nphoenix"                                  
"central ave\nphoenix"                            
[4] "southern ave\nphoenix"                         [5]   "happy valley rd\nste   
\nglendaleaz "               "the americana at brand\n americana way\nglendale"
```

Here the problem is my original csv file does not contain backslashes, but when i read it backslashes appear. Original csv file is as below

```
[1] "peoria ave               [2] "wood dr
     nste                          nphoenix"       
     npeoria"
```

As you can see, they are actually separated by "ENTER" but when i read it in R using read.csv() they are replaced by backslashes.

Comment: You should edit your string to show how it is actually represented in `r`, (i.e. escaped backslashes ``\\``)

Comment: The code you provided cannot be reproduced in R. plus you talk about slashes and provide backslash? if you want to add backslashes u should double them. like `vec <- c("abc\\edw\\www")`

Comment: @SanderVanderZeeuw  I have provided more information, please go through it. I think the backslashes are not actually there. They appear when I read them in R.

Comment: @user2474387 try to use `read.table('blabla.csv',sep=",")`

Comment: Before you do anything to your data, please try `cat(vec, sep="\n")` and check what you get. I suspect the data is just fine, and you're getting confused by `print`'s use of `\n` to represent newlines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

another solution :

```
 sub("\\\\.*", "", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vec <- c("abc\\edw\\www", "nmn\\ggg", "rer\\qqq\\fdf")
sub("([^\\\\])\\\\.*","\\1", vec)
[1] "abc" "nmn" "rer"
```

Answer (score 1):

`strssplit(vec,  "\\\\")` should do the job.

TO select the first element `[[1]][1]` 2nd `[[1]][2]`