# R Trim characters of items in Vector

Tags: r, string

I need to figure out how to trim the characters for every entry in a character vector.  I have searched and tried to use a ^ when referring back to the vector but it has not worked. I am sure there is a simple way to do this that I am not aware of.

Example:

```
CV <- c("ABC_001", "ABC_002", "DEF_003", "DEF_004", "GHIJKLM_005", "GHIJKLM_006")
```

Desired format of character vector CV:

```
"ABC","ABC","DEF","DEF","GHIJKLM","GHIJKLM"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `library(stringr)` and `str_extract(CV, "[A-Z]*")`. If anticiapting lowercase letters as well `str_extract(CV, "[a-zA-Z]*")`

Comment: Remove from the underscore back `sub("_.*", "", CV)`

Comment: @RichScriven - surely a duplicate - maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187552/removing-everything-after-first-backslash-in-a-string is close enough ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub("[^A-Z]", "", CV)`

https://regex101.com/
I found this website very helpful for testing regular expressions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In this particular example it seems that you want to more to *split* your strings using the underscore symbol. If that is the case you can use `strsplit`:

```
sapply (strsplit (CV, split = "_"), "[", 1)
```