# R remove all characters after a slash in a dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have some rows that need to have everything after a slash removed

```
x1\
myco\
myco\
myco/fungicide
```

is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Use `trimws("myco/fungicide", whitespace = "/.*")#[1] "myco"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [removing everything after first 'backslash' in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187552/removing-everything-after-first-backslash-in-a-string)

Comment: i should have been more specific, there are many different words in this column, e.g.: herbicide/fungicide, insecticide/butane etc.

Answer (score 1):

We may use `trimws`

```
df1$x1 <- trimws(df1$x1, whitespace = "/.*")
```